# ¿Por qué cuando creo un archivo de texto se duplica con el signo ~ en linux?

Tags: linux, shell, touch

tengo esta duda puesto que he visto que cuando creo un archivo de texto o html en un servidor de linux se crea un duplicado con el mismo nombre pero al final le agrega el siguiente signo ~, por ejemplo:

```
ejemplo
ejemplo~
```

o también:

```
ejemplo.html
ejemplo.html~
```

tengo curiosidad de por que sucede esto, tambien he visto que se crea de la siguiente forma:

```
ejemplo
ejemplo~
#ejemplo#
```

o también:

```
ejemplo.html
ejemplo.html~
#ejemplo.html#
```

el comando que uso para crear los archivos de texto es touch y para crear el html utilizo emacs, les agradezco mucho si me pueden ayudar con esta duda.

Answer (score 2):

Es un simple caracter creado por algunos programas editores para indicar que es un respaldo. Tengo entendido que algunos editores como `emacs` o `gedit`, entre otros, los crean. Algunos otros editores, como `vim` crean otro tipo de archivos con extensión `.swp`. En otras ocasiones `emacs` crea archivos con los caracteres `#`, por ejemplo `#archivo#`

Es regular que lo encuentres mientras se está editando el archivo con el mismo nombre, salvo la tilde. Tal vez porque lo tienes abierto con emacs por un lado (en una terminal) y lo estás viendo desde otra terminal.